# Transit visa in Toronto

Tags: transit, canada, transit-visas, ukrainian-citizens, yyz

We are traveling from Europe to US with connection in Toronto. We are Ukrainian. Do we need transit visa for the change in Toronto?

Comment: I suppose we wil not leave airport. So we will not step on Canadian land

Comment: not relevant. If airside transit is not available you will mix with general people. Use the link in the duplicate to find out what you need.